# Put the first chapter letter in uppercase and change the color?

Tags: formatting, color

I want to change the look of my chapter:

- The first letter should be in UPPERCASE.
- The first letter should be in different color.
- Before and after the chapiter, I want some decoration: | My chapiter |
- If possible, not show the chapter number.

It is possible to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this. For more, we would need to know what you have tried by now:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% This approach will break with diacritics on pdfTeX
% \def\getfirst#1#2\nil{#1}%
% \def\getrest#1#2\nil{#2}%
% \titleformat\chapter
%   [block]
%   {\Huge\bfseries}
%   {}% no label
%   {0pt}
%   {| {\color{red}\MakeUppercase{\getfirst#1\nil}}\getrest#1\nil\ |}

% This won't, I hope :)
\usepackage{xstring}
\titleformat\chapter
  [block]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}% no label
  {0pt}
  {\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\first]%
  | {\color{red}\MakeUppercase{\first}}\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}\ |}

\begin{document}

\chapter{íorem}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{ipsum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

---

As reported, the code above breaks with a `\tableofcontents`. An more robust alternative, if the user doesn't mind adding an extra pair of braces is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% A more robust solution:
% Requires the user to type \chapter{{Í}orem} instead of \chapter{íorem}
\titleformat\chapter
  [block]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}% no label
  {0pt}
  {| \textcolor{red}#1 |}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{{Í}orem}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{{I}psum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice to note that this fails with diacritics in `pdflatex` :)

Comment: @yo' Indeed... `\getfirst` would remove the diacritic mark from the letter and it would break the whole thing. I added another version with `xstring` that will not break (in this case, at least). Thanks :)

Comment: It works, thank you! I have just a little problem with the table of content: TeX capacity exceeded. Looks like an infinite loop somewhere. I will check that.

Comment: @Le-Dragon-Dev This is why we usually ask for a MWE. There are *many* possibilities that can only be known through a MWE. The problem with this approach is that it uses fragile commands, plus diacritics, plus writing to external files, plus... So it *will* break somehow. If you don't mint typing `\chapter{{Í}psum}` instead of just `\chapter{Ípsum}`, a much safer solution is `\titleformat\chapter[block]{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{| \textcolor{red}#1 |}`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ok, it is working now. :) Sorry, the next time, I will post a MWE first. Thanks a lot.