# Change first letter of section heading

Tags: sectioning

I want to change the first letter of my section heading.
It should be a little bit larger then the rest of the heading and have a different color.

This is what I tried using the example from [Put the first chapter letter in uppercase and change the color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433943/put-the-first-chapter-letter-in-uppercase-and-change-the-color), but I could not adapt it to my usecase.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{189, 71, 47}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat\section
{\LARGE\bf}
{}% no label
{0pt}
{\textcolor{myred}#1}

\begin{document}
    
    \section*{{{S}}tudium}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this makes the whole heading larger and breaks the spacing before and after it.

[image]

What I got to work was `\section*{{\LARGE \textcolor{myred}{S}}tudium}` but I thought maybe there is a nicer way to do this.

Comment: Unlreated `\bf` was depreciated in 1993!!! use `\bfseries`. Additionally please always make a full minimal example not sniplets like this.

Comment: This might work `\newcommand\MyFirst[1]{{\Huge\textcolor{myred}{#1}}}` then use `{\MyFirst#1}` instead of `{\textcolor{myred}#1}` and use `\section*{Studium}`. Note that it is fragile in that it does not work with `\section*{Ést}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `explicit`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\LARGE\bfseries}
  {}% no label
  {0pt}
  {\formatfirstchar}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{189, 71, 47}

\newcommand{\formatfirstchar}[1]{\formatfirstcharaux#1}% first remove braces
\newcommand{\formatfirstcharaux}[1]{\textcolor{myred}{\Huge#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Studium}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you will need braces around the first character if it is not in the ASCII range.

Comment: This works like expected. But the spacing of the heading is still broken (or resetted?) May I ask you how I can fix this in your example?

Comment: @AndiLeni You use the `\titlespacing` command to set the spacing to your liking.